# How to set repeatInterval as Every two days for UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

How to set UILocalNotification to repeat every two days, every three days, etc...? Without using default NSCalendarUnits?

Answer (score 0):

You cant repeat it, within two days ,Locallnotification only allow 4 repeat Intervals

either by Day, Week,Month or Year,

its an Enum Value you canat customize it, the only solution I see is you calculate the time difference and compare it for a two days time and then try to set it again

Answer (score -1):

First we have to set our NSDate on which we will fire our first local notification.
Once the notification is called set for next notification.

```
NSDate *afterTwoDays = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:+2*24*60*60];
```

Set the required parameters:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
localNotification.fireDate =afterTwoDays;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Body";
localNotification.alertAction = @"Alert";
localNotification.repeatInterval=0;
localNotification.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question.